# Remove my app from android account manager "add account"

Tags: android, accountmanager, account-management

When user create new account in my app, I create new account in android account manager.
So user can see his account in settings->accounts and synch...

So question: is it possible to remove my app from list when user click "add new account" in accounts and synch? User should not see my app in this list, but still can create account in my app.

PS. I don't want to open activity when clicked add account, I just want not display my app point in list.

I have in my manifest:

```
 <service
        android:name="myPackage.authenticator.AuthenticationService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" 
            android:resource="@xml/authenticator" /> 
    </service>
```

And my authenticator:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<account-authenticator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:accountType="myType"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:smallIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand, you do not want users to have multiple accounts of your service in a device. I see two options here:

1. Manage if user has already added an account. When user navigates to Settings > Accounts > Add account and choose your service, you will check if there is any registered account on the device. If there is, reject the new authentication.
2. Disable `"myPackage.authenticator.AuthenticationService"` right after user adds her first account (may not be safe), so that system (Settings app) will not be able to locate your service when it is parsing for authentication providers.

Comment: Thx for the answer. But I can't find any ways to stop this service. Any ideas?

Comment: You mean "how to disable"? Please refer to [`PackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html)

Comment: I checked it. And what I got: I create new account and then disable my AuthService. Then (when I need it) I enable this service and want to get my saved account. But this account not available, it was removed when I disable the service. So I can't disable my Service. And, likely, it is impossible to do what I want...  Any way, thx for help.

Comment: A bit of extra work and overhead, but you can go with option 1.

Comment: Yea. I think it would be the best solution in my case.

Comment: @ozbek how to implement that option 1 ??

Comment: @KJEjava48 that's for you (the service provider) to decide :)